# Retornar todos os valores de uma determinada propriedade em uma Array de objetos Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Tenho uma determinada array

```
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Leandro',
    age: 36
  },
  {
    name: 'Joaquim',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Maria',
    age: 25
  }
]
```

Se desejo retornar a propriedade name na primeira posição faço o seguinte

```
console.log(people[0].name)
```

Como faço para retornar todos os nomes contidos na propriedade name?
O resultado desejado é esse:

Leandro, Joaquim, Maria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você cria uma nova array utilizando o método [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) da array original:

```js
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Leandro',
    age: 36
  },
  {
    name: 'Joaquim',
    age: 29
  },
  {
    name: 'Maria',
    age: 25
  }
];
var names = people.map(person => person.name);
console.log(names);
```